# What is trace-ability matrix in manual testing.? How to calculate or estimate.?

Tags: manual-testing

I have newly changed my company on manual testing role and my manager asked me to make trace-ability matrix for the requirements or test cases (I am not sure). However, this is the first time I am hearing about this word 'trace-ability matrix'. However, on some blogs based on the info provided, I understood it is similar like writing business scenario, test scenario and test cases. Is my understanding correct.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is a Traceability Matrix?**

It is used to track the requirements and to check the current project requirements are met. That is, a traceability matrix is a document that co-relates any two-baseline documents that require a many-to-many relationship to check the completeness of the relationship.

**Requirement Trace-ability Matrix**

Requirement Trace-ability Matrix or RTM captures all requirements proposed by the client or development team and their trace-ability in a single document delivered at the conclusion of the life-cycle.

In simple words, it is a document that maps and traces user requirement with test cases. The main purpose of Requirement Traceability Matrix is to see that all test cases are covered so that no functionality should miss while testing.

**RTM Parameter includes:**

```
Requirement ID
Risks
Requirement Type and Description
Trace to design specification
Unit test cases
Integration test cases
System test cases
User acceptance test cases
Trace to test script
```

There are three types of Traceability Matrix as per my knowledge

```
Forward traceability
Backward or reverse traceability
Bi-directional traceability ( Forward+Backward)
```

**Forward traceability:** This matrix is used to check whether the project progresses in the desired direction and for the right product. It makes sure that each requirement is applied to the product and that each requirement is tested thoroughly. It maps requirements to test cases.

**Backward or reverse traceability:** It is used to ensure whether the current product remains on the right track. The purpose behind this type of traceability is to verify that we are not expanding the scope of the project by adding code, design elements, test or other work that is not specified in the requirements. It maps test cases to requirements.

**Bi-directional traceability ( Forward+Backward):** This traceability metrics ensures that all requirements are covered by test cases. It analyzes the impact of a change in requirements affected by the defect in a work product and vice versa.

**Advantage of Requirement Traceability Matrix**

```
It confirms 100% test coverage
It highlights any requirements missing or document inconsistencies
It shows the overall defects or execution status with a focus on business requirements
It helps in analyzing or estimating the impact on the QA team's work with respect to revisiting or re-working on the test cases
```

Answer (score 0):

The `traceability matrix` is a common and really useful tool for the testing procedures. Thanks to the matrix results it is possible to obtain some very important **coverage** metrics related to the test procedures. You have to fix two metrics as table inputs (e.g. *x* values and *y* values) and to insert a cross in the cells where the relationship between the two inputs is satisfied.  In particular, some common traceability matrix are:

1. `test cases <--> requirements`: this kind of matrix helps the testers to estimate the coverage of the realized test cases for the given results. Empty cells in this table means that more test cases have to be produced to cover all the given requirements,
2. `requirements <--> source code`: this matrix helps to understand if some produced code is not covered by any requirement. An empty cell can be caused by the insufficient requirements number or by code that is superfluous,
3. `test cases <--> source code`: this matrix is useful to understand what is the percentage of the tested code. More than one reason can cause an empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

"A requirements traceability matrix (RTM) is a simple and effective tool that allows to establish and maintain bidirectional traceability for your project.

As the name suggests a RTM is nothing more than a table that displays the relation between different development artifacts. Due to its simplicity it can be created with the most basic tool – for example with excel. It sometimes even makes sense to draw it on a white board to make it visible to everyone on the team. Depending on the purpose you are creating the RTM for, it can visualize direct links between ‘linked’ artifacts, shows cumulated views on entire ‘traces’."

[https://blogs.itemis.com/en/how-to-create-a-requirements-traceability-matrix]